# Access Task Scheduler From asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I would like to access the windows Task scheduler from asp page.
For this I use Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper. First I try in C# console and it works well:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
 ...
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {          
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {

            TaskFolder tf = ts.RootFolder;
            Console.WriteLine("\nRoot folder tasks ({0}):", tf.Tasks.Count);
            foreach (Task t in tf.Tasks)
            {
                try
                {
                        Console.WriteLine(t.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(t.State);
                        Console.WriteLine(t.NextRunTime);
                        Console.WriteLine(t.LastRunTime);
                        Console.WriteLine(t.LastTaskResult);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
```

Then I put the same code in the asp.net page. But my webpage doesn't show anything and there is also no error:

```
using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
    {

        TaskFolder tf = ts.RootFolder;
        foreach (Task t in tf.Tasks)
        {
            try
            {
                    Response.Write("Key: " + t.Name);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
}
}
```

For what I see it doesn't go inside the foreach loop. Maybe it's a problem to access the task scheduler from webpage but i can't find a way to solve the problem.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Try wrapping the `using` block with `try..catch..` block and debug it so that you can come to know why "it doesn't go inside the foreach loop" and if any exception is thrown before entering `foreach` loop.

Comment: I try but it shows nothing, no exception and no error

Comment: You told it doesn't go inside foreach loop, so enclose lines from: `TaskFolder tf = ts.RootFolder;` until the end of `foreach` loop. Then you can come to know why it doesn't enter foreach loop.

Comment: there is no error but what i guess is it doesn't enter in the foreach loop because it find nothing or can't access it so no answer